# Is it possible to filter nested array objects by their fields in MongoDB $match aggregation stage?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a user review collection in MongoDB which stores product reviews by users. In addition I have a user reply collection which are replies to a user review.

User review has the following document structure:

```
{
    username: 'John',
    content: 'I liked the product',
}
```

User reply has the following document structure:

```
{
    username: 'John',
    content: 'I liked the product',
    userReviewId: ObjectID('blabla...'),
    status: 'REJECTED' // or can be 'APPROVED'
}
```

I want to make an aggregation which would look up all user reviews with replies with the status `APPROVED` only. I tried the following aggregation in MongoDB shell:

```js
db.getCollection('UserReview').aggregate(
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "UserReply",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "userReview",
      "as": "replies"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "replies": {
        "$elemMatch": {"status":"REJECTED"}
      }
    }
  }
]
)
```

If a certain user review has replies that are both approved and rejected, the above query will fetch a user review with both types of replies like so:

```
{
    username: 'John',
    content: 'I liked the product',
    replies: [
        {
            content: 'reply1'
            userReviewId: ObjectID('blabla...'),
            status: 'REJECTED'
        },
        {
            content: 'reply1'
            userReviewId: ObjectID('blabla...'),
            status: 'APPROVED'
        }
    ]
    
}
```

However I expected the result to be as follows, that is to include only approved replies in `replies` field of user review:

```
{
    username: 'John',
    content: 'I liked the product',
    replies: [
        {
            content: 'reply1'
            userReviewId: ObjectID('blabla...'),
            status: 'APPROVED' // or can be 'APPROVED'
        }
    ]
    
}
```

The only way I found to actually get only approved replies is to use `$filter` operation in projection stage:

```js
$addFields: {
  replies: {
    $filter: {
      input: '$replies',
      as: 'reply',
      cond: { $in: ['$$reply.status', ['APPROVED']] }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to performing the filtering of replies under `$match` stage or this is only possible within projections/addFields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lookup with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- let pass localField to match with foreignField in pipeline,
- `$expr` to match id and match `status` is approved inside `$and` condition

```
db.UserReview.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "UserReply",
      "let": { id: "$_id" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$userReviewId"] } },
              { status: "APPROVED" }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "replies"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/97Q_EVuFZJT)

Comment: Is there any added value from `$and`? According to this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/  "MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions."

Comment: Also let's say `replies` was a nested field in `UserReview` collection so no lookup was needed. Would there be any other option except for `$filter`?

Comment: *Is there any added value from $and?* both expression are different, here we are checking both fields (id) are equal or not that are already exists in document so that is and expression match, and second we are matching status with external value so that is not an expression, but the {status: "APPROVED"} full condition is a expression for the $and.

Comment: *Also let's say replies was a nested field* yes that is good approach to manage comments in same collection and no need to lookup, $filter is the beast option.

Comment: Regarding `$and` I meant that it is not necessary because `$and` is implied with all conditions inside `$match`. You can try your query in the playground without `$and` to see that the result will be the same as with `$and`.

Comment: yes of course you are right, it will work without $and, this is just for easy to understand conditions.